# Android - Text Delivered ALWAYS returns RESULT OK

Tags: android, sms

I am having a problem with some code and need some help. The code I have here sends a text... But the issue I have is that the code for receiving the text ALWAYS returns RESULT_OK... I can turn a phone off / try a number which I know is not real and it will always return RESULT_OK... Can anyone help me in the right direction, is there something obvious wrong? Have I used the wrong code? Any help would be great! Thanks

The code when I receive the text:

> Blockquote

```
Globals.GlobalContext.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1)
        {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Globals.UpdateStatus("Message was delivered");
                Bundle extras = arg1.getExtras();
                if (extras != null)
                {
                    arg1.getStringExtra("smsNumber");
                    String number = arg1.getStringExtra("smsNumber");
                    Globals.UpdateStatus("Delivered to :" + number);
                    arg1 = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    Globals.UpdateStatus("Sent to a number that I don't know :(");
                }

                break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                Globals.UpdateStatus("Message was NOT delivered");
                break;
            }

        }

    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
```

The code for sending my text :

```
public void SendTextMessageDelivery(String number, String Message)
{
    if ((CheckValidPhoneNumber(number)) && (Message.length() != 0))
    {
        if (!CheckSMSManager())
        {
            StartSMSManager(true);
        }



        //sent
        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Globals.GlobalContext, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
        ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
        sentIntents.add(sentPI);

        //delivered
        Intent DeliveredIntent = new Intent(DELIVERED);
        DeliveredIntent.putExtra("smsNumber", number);

        PendingIntent DeliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Globals.GlobalContext, 0, DeliveredIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
        ArrayList<PendingIntent> DeliveredIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
        DeliveredIntents.add(DeliveredPI);

        ArrayList<String> mSMSMessage = smsManager.divideMessage(Message);
        for (int i = 0; i < mSMSMessage.size(); i++)
        {

        }
        smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(number, null, mSMSMessage, sentIntents, DeliveredIntents);
    }
    else
    {
        if (Message.length() != 0)
        {
            Globals.UpdateStatus("Message was not long enough!");
        }
        else
        {
            Globals.UpdateStatus("Failed to Validate Mobile Number");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons why you might be getting incorrect results. First and foremost: checking `getResultCode()` is not the proper way to determine delivery success or failure. Though many examples use this method, the true result will be on an SMS status message returned from the service center, and passed into the Receiver.

The `Intent` handed to your Receiver will have a single PDU attached as an extra. An `SmsMessage` must be created from this, and the value returned from its `getStatus()` method will be the actual result. For example, your delivery result Receiver might look something like the following (though it would be better to hand the extra to a `Service` for processing).

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.Telephony;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

public class DeliveryResultReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        SmsMessage sms = null;

        byte[] pdu = intent.getByteArrayExtra("pdu");
        String format = intent.getStringExtra("format");

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && format != null) {
            sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu(pdu, format);
        }
        else {
            sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu(pdu);
        }

        int statusCode = sms.getStatus();
        String status = translateDeliveryStatus(statusCode);
        ...
    }

    String translateDeliveryStatus(int statusCode) {
        switch (statusCode) {
            case Telephony.Sms.STATUS_COMPLETE:
                return "Sms.STATUS_COMPLETE";
            case Telephony.Sms.STATUS_FAILED:
                return "Sms.STATUS_FAILED";
            case Telephony.Sms.STATUS_PENDING:
                return "Sms.STATUS_PENDING";
            case Telephony.Sms.STATUS_NONE:
                return "Sms.STATUS_NONE";
            default:
                return "Unknown status code";
        }
    }
}
```

If, after implementing this, you're still getting false positives, then it might be due to how your carrier defines "delivered". Delivery might not mean delivery to the target device. The exact behavior will vary from provider to provider, even down to the service center level. The following may not come from the [best source](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_Service), but it puts it as succinctly as I've seen:

> Some providers allow users to request delivery reports, either via the SMS settings of most modern phones, or by prefixing each message with *0# or *N#. However, the exact meaning of confirmations varies from reaching the network, to being queued for sending, to being sent, to receiving a confirmation of receipt from the target device, and users are often not informed of the specific type of success being reported.